# Java 8 efficient for loop

Tags: java

I have below code snippet, Is any other efficient way exists to achieve the same in java 8. I have tried lambda expression but throws error when i assign some variable inside lambda function.

```
public boolean countUsers(UserDetais details){
  List<SystemProfile> systemProfileDataList = getSystemProfileData();
  int userCountForService = service.getUserCountByService(details.id);
  int vpcUsersCount=0;
  int internetUsersCount=0;

   if (systemProfileDataList != null) {
            SystemProfile sysProfile;
            Iterator profileItr = systemProfileDataList.iterator();
      while (profileItr.hasNext()) {
                SystemProfile sysProfile = (SystemProfile) profileItr.next();

     if(sysProfile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(IPConstants.DEFAULT_MAX_USERS)) {
                    vpcUsersCount = Integer.parseInt(sysProfile.getValue());
                    if (userCountForService > vpcUsersCount) {
                        maxUserFlag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }else if(sysProfile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(IPConstants.DEAULT_MAX_USERS_WITH_INTERNET)) {
                    internetUsersCount = Integer.parseInt(sysProfile.getValue());
                    if (userCountForService > internetUsersCount) {
                        maxUserFlag = true;
                        break;
                    }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Before you worry about efficiency, you need to make the code more readable. It's far more important.

Comment: Please, post your code with java 8 lamdas.

Comment: *to achieve the same* - the same as what? We are not going to decipher your code to guess what it does

Comment: Add commenter to explain what do you make exactly

Comment: Use `for (SystemProfile sysProfile : systemProfileDataList) { ... }`

Comment: I would replace the explicit `Iterator` and `while` loop with a for-each loop: `for (SystemProfile sysProfile : systemProfileDataList)`. No need to use Java 8 streams and lambda expressions here. (Just because Java 8 has streams does not mean they are always better than a simple loop).

Comment: Use a code formatter. It's built into Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
boolean tooManyUsers = getSystemProfileData().stream()
    .anyMatch((SystemProfile s) -> 
            s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(IPConstants.DEFAULT_MAX_USERS)
            && Integer.parseInt(sysProfile.getValue()) < userCountForService
        ||
            s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(IPConstants.DEAULT_MAX_USERS_WITH_INTERNET)
            && Integer.parseInt(sysProfile.getValue()) < internetUsersCount
    );
```

Comment: @Mark How so? I wouldn't mind reworking it anyway, the redundancy of the code between the two alternatives annoys me...

Comment: I'm not really sure just reading the code w/o running it but i really feel that this may cause the error `SystemProfile s ->` I'm not good at lambda please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Mark right, if I want to qualify it I need brackets (otherwise `s ->`alone should be fine). Fixed !